# Ignore all errors in vimrc at vim startup

Tags: vim, ansible, vundle

I am trying to create an Ansible script to set up my mac. One role is to set up vim. A first clone my dot-files into a local folder and symlink them to ~/.
In my vimrc I use vundle to install extension. So I try to start vim to install all extensions like this:

```
- name: vim | Install vundle plugins
  shell: vim  +PluginInstall +qall
```

But when I start this, I get the error:

```
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'molokai'
```

Is it possible to suppress this error messages for the first startup?

Comment: You can include things like custom colorschemes inside try/catch blocks and/or if <loaded condition> finish style include guards. I had the same issues and ended up doing this so that everything still works cleanly if certain plugins aren't installed or disabled.

Comment: @swalladge That also sounds like a good solution, thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Possibly* you could split your vundler config into its own file `vundler.vim`, and on your first startup/ansible script you instead run `vim -u vundler.vim` (you can make it run `:VundleInstall` or whatever else would be required via some commandline flags too, `-E`?).

Then in your regular `vimrc` you just `source vundler.vim` for your regular day to day usage.

Comment: If you can't get the extra command line flag to work you can split it on more level, `vundler-ansible-shim.vim` that just has `source vundler.vim<NEWLINE>:PluginInstall` in it.

Answer (score 11):

You can silence the `E185: Cannot find color scheme 'molokai'` error in your `.vimrc` by setting `silent! colorscheme molokai` then install with i.e.: `vim -E -s -u ~/.vimrc +PlugInstall +qall`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.
The way I solved this, was by using the [stdin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#parameter-stdin) argument of the `shell` module.
I'm passing a new line at `stdin`.

My task looks like this

```
- name: "Install plugins"
  shell: vim +PluginInstall +qall
  args:
      stdin: "\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use  `--clean` arg to get around those startup warnings/errors. Once you're inside vim, if you send a second command, it will pass over those warnings/errors.

This worked for me: `vim --clean '+source ~/.vimrc' +PluginInstall +qall`

(I know this thread is a little old but I came across this issue myself just now.)